# How can I create an Android app with foreground service that monitoring a geofence using Qt?

Tags: qt5, android-service, qt-creator, android-geofence, foreground-service

I'm a beginner in Qt and Android and I have to develop an Android application with a foreground service that monitoring a geofence using Qt. The goal is to ensure that when the user kill the app, the foreground service remains active and continues to monitor the geofence.

I have tried all the possible examples but I haven't succeeded yet. The only example that comes close to what I want is this one: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService.

This example is an app with a foreground service that monitors GPS coordinates and the service works even if you kill the app.

I also found this example that was created using Qt: https://github.com/frankipl/service-test

This example is an app with a background service.

**Is it possible to use the same technique as the second example to start a foreground service using Qt? And how do I create and monitor a Geofence in a foreground service?**

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the question is stil valid. Anyway some time ago I filled this [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70772). The examples there might be what you are looking for.